# start varnish instance with -p

Tags: caching, configuration, varnish, varnish-vcl

I would like to know how to start **Varnish instance with "-p cli_buffer 10000".**

is the following command right way ?

> service varnish reload -p cli_buffer=10000

Answer (score 1):

You can put this in /etc/default/varnish configuration file

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, Place this in your config-file instead. The config is placed at /etc/default/varnish on ubuntu

```
 DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80 \
             -T :6083 \
             -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
             -n varnish \
             -s malloc,5G \
             -p esi_syntax=0x1 \
             -p cli_buffer=10000"
```